# how to check all descendant::w:p that having the child of w:r/w:t of my current node using xslt 2.0?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

This is my Xml document(small snippt).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<w:document xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
<w:body>
<w:p> <!-- Current Node -->
   <w:r>
        <w:pict>
            <w:shape>
                <w:txbxContent>
                    <w:p>
                        <w:r>
                            <w:t>Table 11: Tanjavur NREGS activities
                            </w:t>
                        </w:r>
                    </w:p>

                    <w:p/>
                </w:txbxContent>
            </w:shape>
        </w:pict>
    </w:r>
    <w:r>
        <w:t>CHAPTER IV: Findings and analysis
        </w:t>
    </w:r>
</w:p>

</w:body>
</w:document>
```

Now just assume,`<w:p>`is my current processing Node.Now, here i want to test one condition using . My Condition is,

If it(current processing node) having more than one descendant `<w:p>`that having child `<w:r><w:t>` then only i have to perform some functions inside `<w:when>`.

now i tested like,

```
  <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test="descendant::w:p[2]">

                <!-- here i have to perform some work -->                 
       </xsl:when>
       <xsl:otherwise>
       </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
```

In my above xml document, current processing node having two descendant `<w:p>`. But, only one descendant `<w:p>` having `<w:r><w:t>` childs. Another descendant `<w:p>` is none.

but My above xslt condition is true this case.How to check if both descendant  having `<w:r><w:t>` childs.

Please guide me to get out of this issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
<xsl:when test="count(descendant::w:p[w:r/w:t]) > 1">
```

> more than one descendant `<w:p>` that having child `<w:r><w:t>`

Requirements for the current node translated to XPath:

- Has a descendant `<w:p>` --> `descendant::w:p`
- That `<w:p>` has a child `<w:r>` that has a child `<w:t>` --> `w:p[w:r/w:t]`
- There are more than one of such descendants --> `count(...) > 1`

Answer (score 2):

> If it(current processing node) having more than one descendant `<w:p>`
>   that having child `<w:r><w:t>` then only i have to perform some
>   functions inside `<w:when>`.

**More efficient solution: Use  as the `test` attribute of your conditional instruction, or, better as the predicate of a match patern**:

```
   descendant::w:p[w:r/w:t][2]
```

The above expression is `true()` only when the context node has at least two `w:p` descendents, such that each of these have a `w:r` child that itself has a `w:t` child.

Comment: +1 - If there's more than one, then there's got to be a second one.